# Very First Wordpress Action Hook?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a very first WP Action hook, I am actually looking for a hook that's called even before connecting/calling the Database.

is there any?

I have tried use `'wp'` hook with lowest priority but it still connects to DB.

I have also tried looking at the core WP files, but doesn't seem to find one.

Comment: I guess there is no hook called before `wp`.

Answer (score 1):

[`muplugins_loaded`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded) is the earliest hook.

> Depending on your wordpress setup, you may not have any plugins in the `MU_PLUGINS` directory. In that case this hook may not fire.

The next best hook to trigger is [`plugins_loaded`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded).

**Also check this for more information**

- [WordPress Codex - Action Reference List](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)
- [How to get WordPress' hook run sequence?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162869/84219)
- [Make sense of WP Load Core](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/22534)